# Getting, 'throw typeError(MSG_INVALID_SECRET);' when i run node sever

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication

I forked from a repo of an applications for the purpose of learning about user authentication.  I get this error 'throw typeError(MSG_INVALID_SECRET)' when I run $node server while trying to login .  I am assuming it has something to do with the fact that in controllers/usersController.js I have:

> const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); const secret =
>   process.env.SECRET;

Clearly I need something like process.env in my root directory...I think.  How do I make such a file, what should be in it?  What is the purpose of this file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Start your Node server like this:

```
$ env SECRET="SOME_SECRET_STRING" node server
```

`process.env.SECRET` means "use the [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) called `SECRET` to provide the value".

Comment: That worked!  I guess I am using "SECRET="SOME_SECRET_STRING" instead on the env file.  How do I setup such a file?  Do I just create a file named "process.env" and place something like SECRET="SOME_SECRET_STRING?